# Why is .reduce used instead of reduce()? In flattening an array of arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

This example is from http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.1. 
My question is the first bullet-pointed detail; others may be helpful details, but are additional; also see the first short program to see my question in context.

### - Why is `arrays.reduce()` used instead of `reduce(arrays())`. I know that their's works with the `arrays.reduce`, but why?

This is an answer to a comment that is useful, but additional to the original question.

- My question is with this first program. Since it uses arrays.reduce,
  reduce would be a method of arrays, I am not sure why reduce is a
  method of arrays. The reason might be in the design decisions of
  JavaScript? Thanks, @cookie monster, for that comment!

This is the program with the context of my question-

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));

// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

These next details are additional, but may(or may not) be of use:

I know that the `[]` at the end is used because it is the start parameter in the function reduce so that the other arrays are added to that empty array. I know the `.concat` is putting together the two arrays like `+` with strings, but for arrays. Here is what the reduce function, even though it is standard, looks like:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start){
  var current = start;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}
```

One of their other examples showed my way with a single array, if that helps. It looked like:

```
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b){
  return a + b;
}, 0));
//  10
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Because it's a standard method on all Arrays? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) already exists. There's no real need to redefine it as a global.

Comment: Do you want to know how an array finds its methods? Or are you asking about design decisions of the JavaScript language?

Comment: I think `combine` should be called with the third parameter `array` to be the same as `array.reduce()` btw.

Comment: before [].reduce() was standard, a lot of folks wrote a stand-alone or replacement reduce() functions (ex Prototype, underscore, etc). don't read too much into what's likely an accidental inconsistency in the lessons.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why the arrays.reduce is used instead of the reduce(arrays). Since it uses arrays.reduce, reduce would be a method of arrays, I am not sure why reduce is a method of arrays. The reason might be in the design decisions of JavaScript? Thanks, cookie monster, for that comment!

Comment: @JavaScriptArray - `.reduce()` is made exclusively to operate on arrays.  It is of no use without an array.  Thus, in classic object oriented design, it makes sense to make it a method of the array object.  In object oriented design, you put methods on the objects that they operate on rather than make a giant list of global functions that must be passed the type of data they work on.  There are a whole bunch of benefits to organizing functionality in an object oriented way and Javascript chooses to take advantage of those benefits.

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00, for that comment; it does make sense in object-oriented design to have methods of objects. Array is the object and reduce is the method. It would limit the number of functions needed.

Comment: My question was unclear with the extra details, so I have made some revisions to the question. I now show what is the question with a bullet point, what is additional, but helpful in another bullet point, what is the context of the question as the first highlighted program, and then say that the rest is additional, but maybe helpful. If anyone finds my question unclear, please leave a comment! Thanks!

Comment: I've voted to repoen your question and will turn my comment into an answer and elaborate some more if/when enough people vote to reopen that your question actually gets reopened.

Comment: Thank you, @jfriend00, I thought that your answer was a good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object oriented design, a guiding principle is that you create or declare objects and those objects have a series of methods on them that operate on that particular type of object.  As Javascript is an object oriented language, the built-in functions follow many of the object oriented principles.

`.reduce()` is a function that operates only on Arrays.  It is of no use without an Array to operate on.  Thus, in an object oriented design paradigm, it makes complete sense to place the `.reduce()` function as a method on an `Array` object.

This object-oriented approach offers the following advantages vs. a global `reduce()` function:

1. It is consistent with the object oriented principles used elsewhere in the language.
2. It is convenient to invoke the `.reduce()` function on a particular `array` by using `array.reduce()` and it is obvious from the syntax which array it is operating on.
3. All array operations are grouped as methods on the `Array` object making the API definition more self documenting.
4. If you attempt to do `obj.reduce()` (invoke it on a non-array), you will immediately get an runtime error about an undefined `.reduce()` method.
5. No additional space is taken in the global scope (e.g. no additional global symbol is defined - lessening the chance for accidental overwrite or conflict with other code).

---

If you want to know why anyone ever used a global `reduce()` instead, you would need to understand a little bit about the history of Javascript evolution.  Before ES5 (or for users running browsers who hadn't yet implemented ES5 like IE8), Javascript did not have a built-in `.reduce()` method on the `Array` object.  Yet, some developers who were familiar with this type of useful iteration capability from other languages wanted to to use it in their own Javascript or in their own Javascript framework.

When you want to add some functionality to an existing built-in object like `Array` in Javascript, you generally have two choices.  You can add a method to the prototype (in object-oriented fashion) or you can create a global function that takes the `Array` as its first argument.

For the `Array` object in particular, there are some potential issues with adding iterable methods to the `Array` prototype.  This is because if any code does this type of iteration of an array (a bad way to iterate arrays, but nevertheless done by many):

```
for (var prop in array)
```

they will end up iterating not only the elements of the array, but also any iterable properties of the array.  If a new method is assigned to the prototype with this type of syntax:

```
Array.prototype.myMethod = function() {}
```

Then, this new method will end up getting iterated with the `for (var prop in array)` syntax and it will often cause problems.

So, rather than adding a new method to the prototype, a safer alternative was to just use a global function and avoid this issue.

Starting in ES 5.1, there is a way using `Object.defineProperty()` to add non-iterable methods to an object or prototype so for newer browsers, it is now possible to add methods to a prototype that are not subject to the problem mentioned above.  But, if you wanted to support older browsers (like IE8) and use `reduce()` type of functionality, you're still stuck with these ancient limitations.

So ... even though a global `reduce()` is less object oriented and is generally not as desirable in Javascript, some older code went that route for legitimate safety/interoperability reasons.  Fortunately, we are putting that road behind us as old version of IE drop off in usage (thank god for Microsoft dropping XP support to finally accelerate the demise of old versions of IE).  And newer browsers already contain `array.reduce()` built in.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) was/is influenced by the language [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), a dialect of [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_programming_language).  In Scheme [higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) are a **key** component/feature of the language.  In fact the `reduce` function is pretty much equivalent to the `fold` function in Scheme. In the case of the `reduce` function in JavaScript, the creators of the language noticed that programmers often need to traverse arrays in a certain fashion, and gave programmers a *higher order* function where they can pass in a function to specify how they want to manipulate the data.  Having higher order functions allows programmers to abstract redundant code therefore creating shorter, cleaner, more readable code.

You can use the `reduce` function in JavaScript to do many things other than flatten lists.  Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight#Examples) an example.